# Change CSS attributes on part of a HTML element's innerHTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find a way to change part of the innerHTML of several elements with the class `.studentYear`, but I keep getting a JavaScript `undefined` error. Here's what I am trying.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('studentYear').innerHTML.indexOf(" ").css('color', '#800000');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordionContainer">
      <div class="studentYear">Freshman (A1 Schedule)</div>
        <div class="accordionContent" style="display:none;">
            <p class="studentTerm">Fall</p>
           <p>Content</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

I see now that it is a collection (array type). I need to access the innerHTML for each item in the collection and change the style attribute on only part of the innerHTML, in this case everything in parentheses "(A1 Schedule)". I still get the undefined error if following the suggestions made below.

Comment: Have you tried to define the collection of elements as a variable, first? Then loop through each of the elements and run the `innerHTML.index....` on each element that way? What exactly is undefined? Do you have any more errors?

Comment: You are getting undefined because indexOf returns, well, an index, which is a number. Also, you are trying to use innerHTML on the result of getElementsByClassName, which returns an array of DOM elements... Break it up a little bit, and the solution will become apparent.

Comment: You're getting undefined because `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` returns an *array*, and arrays don't have an `innerHTML` property.

Comment: You can't call `innerHTML` in array. You have to `foreach` on them. You also can't call `css` method on a string. Simply get the `innerHTML` and make `string.replace` on it. I don't know what you except so I can't help you much...

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection which is an array like object. You cannot call `innerHTML` on this object, you must iterate (jquery selectors abstract this step). Speaking of, `css` is a jquery method, not a dom node method - you're looking for `style` which is an object containing each style property. Not sure the point of the `indexOf`. Can you give an example of your expected behavior / output?

Comment: Sorry, I should have realized that it was a collection. The main goal I am trying to achieve is to only change the color of the text in parentheses for each student year. So for my example it would be part of the string "(A1 Schedule)". How can I achieve this from a collection of elements?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of problems with what you're trying.

- `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is kind of like an array, but not quite, so you can't call `innerHTML` on it directly
- `indexOf(" ")` will give you the first index of the space, which would possibly be before the element. It would also give you a number.
- `css()` doesn't exist in vanilla JavaScript, that's a jQuery thing.

It looks like you're wanting to set that element to use `color: #000000`. That means you actually need to set the `style` attribute.

This code would do the trick, applying it to every one of them with the class `studentYear`.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('studentYear'), function (element) {
    element.style = 'color: #F00';
});
```

The `Array.prototype.forEach.call` lets us treat the `HTMLCollection` as an array and loop through it. Then for each element, we'll set it's style attribute to `color: #F00` (or whatever you want, I used red to make it obvious).

If you need to support older browsers, you shouldn't access the `style` attribute directly, instead use `setAttribute` instead:

```
element.setAttribute('style', 'color: #F00');
```

Comment: This gets the collection, but there is still no way to access the innerHTML.indexOf(). I need to change the attribute for only part of the innerHTML from each item in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have said, you have to loop through the objects and set each one since it is similar to an array. Something like this:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('studentYear');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].setAttribute('style', 'color: #F00');
}
```

Edit: Just saw samanime's answer, which seems a little more elegant in my opinion.